# Adding a jar in WEB-INF\lib in POM

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I have few jar files which I am not getting from any repositories.I have these jar files in WEB-INF\lib folder for src directory. Is there a way to add these as dependencies in POM without specifying the actual path of the jar files (relative path is fine..)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can define the dependencies as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.artifact</artifactId>
    <version>a.b</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/WEB-INF/lib/my.artifact.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Essentially you specify the scope as `<system>` to indicate to maven not to look for this in a repository and `<systemPath>` to indicate where it is.  This would be an absolute path, but can take maven properties.  Details [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies).

You would do this for each such jar that you have.

Answer (score 4):

You should install these files in your local repository. Ideally, you have a shared repository installed on your local machine or on a remote server (Nexus, Artifactory, Archiva) and you deploy your jars to that repository.

To install a file locally, you can use the following command (taken from the Maven install plugin website):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=your-artifact-1.0.jar \
                     [-DpomFile=your-pom.xml] \
                     [-Dsources=src.jar] \
                     [-Djavadoc=apidocs.jar] \
                     [-DgroupId=org.some.group] \
                     [-DartifactId=your-artifact] \
                     [-Dversion=1.0] \
                     [-Dpackaging=jar] \
                     [-Dclassifier=sources] \
                     [-DgeneratePom=true] \
                     [-DcreateChecksum=true]
```

In your pom, you can then reference those jars as regular dependencies. For more information on the Maven Install Plugin, take a look at their [website](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/).

Answer (score 4):

Using [Apache Maven Dependency Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/)

- `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` and you will find `target/dependencies` folder filled with all the dependencies, including transitive.
- while downloading dependencies face issues, use `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` and try again.

Using eclipse:

1. Right click on **Properties** of the project.
2. Select **Deployment Assembly** option.
3. Click on **Add** button.
4. Select **Java Build Path Entries** as follows.

[image]

5. Click on **Next** to get the following wizard:
   [image]
6. Select **Maven Dependencies**.
7. Click on **finish**.

Comment: was searching for two days for this.. really worked like magic

Answer (score 1):

As Guillaume correctly points out, just install the jars into your local/corporate repository.

If that is impossible for some reason, use the `${basedir}` [property](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ${project.baseuri} to get the path of your project and then go to the WEB_INF/lib directory from there. [This page](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html) has a list of such properties that you can access in your pom.